# Error on import in index.js in a basic React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
'use strict'

import Title from './App'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

render(
  React.createElement(Title),
  document.querySelector('[data-js="app"]')
)
```

I got an error in line 3:

Line:

```
import Title from './App'
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in bundle.js:48
```

App.js

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'

var Title = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Título')
  }
})

export default Title
```

Brackets show this error:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import'.import Title from './App'
ESLint (1): ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved                import Title from './App'
```

Comment: what's in app.js?

Comment: what are you trying to import? if you're trying to import `Title` this may be a silly question but are you exporting it from `App`? if you're just doing `export default App` in App.js then you're only exporting `App` more than likely. I'm new to React so I could be wrong here but you could trying exporting the `Title` class from App and then bringing it in with `import { Title } from './App'`

Comment: App.js added on question

Comment: Looks like it's not being transpiled.

Comment: if its not being transpiled the error is in webpack.config but seems like everything is okay in this archive